# AutoSave MS: Is there a local storage solution?

Tags: windows-10, backup, microsoft-office, autosave

My files are typically 0.5-2 GB, which are too slow to use on my broadband and impossible to use when away from my home connection.
Saving to OneDrive is a way to stop my work.
Is there an alternative way to create, keep and access backups (say 1-3 generations) as files are modified? WordPerfect did a good job in this and other features so I still use it, but unfortunately has lost the battle.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/file-history-in-windows-5de0e203-ebae-05ab-db85-d5aa0a199255 Windows File History combined with a good sized external drive. [Alternate page for Win 10 & 11](https://uk.pcmag.com/migrated-3765-windows-10/85293/how-to-back-up-and-restore-your-files-in-windows-10)

Comment: Thank you. I already backup my important files to an external USB drive. This takes quite a time because of the large number of semi-archived files involved. So it is done weekly or so, but does nothing to rescue me from a bad editing decision that I did not notice before saving. However, I should like to duplicate/ improve upon what WordPerfect does, which is to store the current version on opening (as a backup), then also store the new current version on saving. And preferably do this for say 3 generations.  This would be relevant only for active files, a small subset of the folder contents.

Comment: That's why I suggested File History, not backing them up. Using OneDrive with Microsoft Word will also enable the kind of versioning you want. There is also [System Restore](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/use-system-restore-a5ae3ed9-07c4-fd56-45ee-096777ecd14e) which if you enable it for that drive will give you a "Previous Versions" right click menu where you should have a few versions of history for files. Basically you just need to start using up to date programs and methods.